# Change of Variables and Integration Domain

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

This is a purely theoretic problem which doesn't involve any specific calculation.

Suppose we have two coordinate systems for $\mathbb R^2$ and they are $xy$-system and $uv$-system respectively.

Suppose we have $x=g(u,v)$ and $y=h(u,v)$ and we know both $g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable, i.e. $C^1$.

Suppose the mapping $T(u,v):=(g(u,v),h(u,v))=(x,y)$ is injective.

Suppose we have a small rectangle $S$ in the $uv$-plane. The general idea to prove the formula for change of variables is approximating the image of $S$ under $T$ in the $xy$-plane by a parallelogram in the $xy$-plane. People use the image of the boundary of $S$ under $T$ to calculate the area of the parallelogram I quoted. By doing this, people use the fact that $T$ preserves boundaries, i.e. $T(\partial S)=\partial [T(S)].$

**My question is**, how can we assure that $T(\partial S)=\partial [T(S)]$ ?

If the equality is not true, then how do we approximate the parallelogram in the $xy$-plane?

I know the equality is true if $T$ is a homeomorphism, but under our assumption, $T$ may not have a continuous inverse(though $T^{-1}$ is always defined on $T(S)$ due to our injective condition).

---

**Edit:** I think I missed an important condition that the Jacobian determinant $\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}$ is nonzero in the interior of the integral domain in the $uv$-plane. If we have this condition, then we can use the Inverse Function Theorem to guarantee the existence of local homeomorphism, and then our operation is valid.(Am I right?)

---

**Second Edit:** In my calculus book, the formula for change of variables doesn't require the Jacobian determinant is nonzero. I am stuck here again.

---

**Third Edit:** Intuitively I feel like the Jacobian must be nonzero and so I am trying to prove it now. Suppose the Jacobian is zero on a set with positive measure, which is denoted by $E$. The key equation in the proof is that $$dx\,dy= \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} du\,dv.$$ On $E$, we can have some $du,dv$ s.t. $du>0$ and $dv>0$. Since the Jacobian is zero on $E$, we have $dx\,dy=0$. So a rectangle with area of $du\,dv(>0)$ is mapped to a set with zero measure by an injective continuous function $T$, where $T$ is defined as above. Intuitively I feel like this statement is wrong, but I can not prove it. Any help with deriving a contradiction will be appreciate.

Comment: The Jacobian acts as scale factor and so must non-zero.  Consider x=u/2, and y=v/2 ; perfectly reasonable but scaled.  On a deeper level where u,v ->x,y has complications.  Do you have a multidimensional calculus book; say Spivak's book "Calculus on Manifolds"?   I have found that to be easy and clear, to understand and read.  There are other books but most are to clarify certain applications and that obscures things.

Comment: @rrogers Hi Rogers, I understand intuitively the Jacobian acts as a scale factor and it should be non-zero. I have checked Spivak's book(Theorem 3.13 on p. 67), in which he directly assumes that the Jacobian is non-zero, without any proof. What I want is a rigorous proof that the Jacobian is indeed non-zero. Thanks for your info anyway.

Comment: Right, but did you look at 3.14 ?  This characterizes the case of J() =0 as having 0-measure.

Comment: @rrogers I didn’t but I find it now. It’s a really impressive result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is bounded then you can find a compact subset $K$ which contains an open neighbourhood of $S\cup\partial S$. Now $T$ restricts to a continuous bijective mapping $K\to T(K)$ where $K$ is compact and $T(K)$ is Hausdorff, hence a homeomorphism.

If $S$ is not bounded then $\partial(TS)=T(\partial S)$ can fail. Take the vertical strip $S=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x\leq 1\}$ and consider $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $T(x,y)=(x,\arctan y)$.

Comment: Hi Hakkiuz, for the bounded case, we conclude that $T$ has a continuous inverse because it maps closed sets to closed sets right?

Comment: I don't quite understand; take the case where S is closed (perhaps a bifurcation occurs), then it would seem you could not find that neighborhood on the boundary unless the outer edge was of measure zero.  But it's been a long time since my real analysis course "drug me over the coals".

Comment: @SamWong Hi, Sam. Every continuous bijection from a compact space into a Hausdorff space is actually a homeomorphism. You can indeed prove it arguing that it takes closed sets to closed sets, or as in [this proof](https://hidenori-shinohara.github.io/2019/08/24/continuous-bijection.html), arguing that it takes open sets to open sets.

Comment: @rrogers I don't think I'm following you. Every bounded set $S$ can be covered by an open ball (say $S\subseteq B$) and then that open ball is still bounded, so the closure $K=\overline B$ is a compact set that contains $B$, which is a neighbourhood of $S$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Your probably right, but "Every bounded set S can be covered by an open ball" seems to be quite general.  Does it just refer to R^n or Manifolds?   I am thinking of intersecting Manifolds (i.e. continuation through/on Varieties) and Point-Set Topology; but I will do some research.

Comment: @rrogers "you can cover it by an open ball" is basically the definition of a bounded set in any metric space.